# "global" calculations for sorted sets

Tags: redis

With a sorted set, is there an easy way to compute "global" values, for instance the average, median, max, min, etc. of all the scores in the set, or do I always need to extract the scores and do the calculations myself (which is a bit of a pain ...)?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it all with ZCARD and ZRANGE (withscore of course).

- Min: ZRANGE on index 0
- Max: ZRANGE on max index (ZCARD value)
- Median: ZRANGE on the middle index (ZCARD/2)
- Average: you can store the total off all score in another counter and then divide it by the ZCARD value

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way for doing it. There are not many aggregation commands.

Edit: if that's what you have to do, maybe sorted set (or even redis) is not the way to go. Can you elaborate on your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another key with the sum of all the scores in the sorted set. You will have to update it manually (in a multi/exec probably) on every insert/update/delete of the sorted set. Then you can get the value and divide it by the ZCARD to get the average.